# Take a one time permission from user

Tags: swift

I have a problem with taking permission from the users, my application is about the users ask and the app answers.
how can I make a pop-up window, when the user opens the application first time, the popup appears and ask for permission to save the question.

Answer (score 1):

**1. Display an alert view:**

```
let alert = UIAlertController()

alert.title = "This is your title of the alert"
alert.message = "This is your question"

alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Answer one", style: .default , handler:{ (UIAlertAction)in
// Let's save the user's choice for later
UserDefaults.standard.set("UserChoseOptionOne", forKey: "myReallyImportantQuestion")    
}))

alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Answer two", style: .default , handler:{ (UIAlertAction)in
// Let's save the user's choice for later 
UserDefaults.standard.set("UserChoseOptionTwo", forKey: "myReallyImportantQuestion")     

}))

alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ask me later", style: .cancel, handler:{ (UIAlertAction)in

 // Let's not do anything here. 
 // The user can't decide at the moment and let's ask the next time your app is opened again 

}))

self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

**2. In your viewDidLoad**

```
// Here we have to differentiate between three cases!

// Case 1: This is the very first time our dear user opened our cool app
// or
// Case 2: This is not the first time, we already asked our important question and we have an answer already!
// or
// Case 3: This is not the first time, the last time we asked our question, the user decided to choose later. Later is now!

if let option = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "myReallyImportantQuestion") {

    // Here we handle Case 2. Maybe you don't want to do anything here
    // We already have the user's choice saved in option
    // We can do whatever we want with that

}else{

    // Here are the cases 1 and 3.
    // In here you can paste the code from "1. Display an alert view"
    // If you feel fancy today, you can also make a function out of "1. Display an alert view" and call it in here
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Create the userDefaults key
You now need to create a new static let called numberOfTimesLaunchedApp, this will be used to read and write to the userDefaults so that we can keep track of how many times the app has been opened

Comment: Why do you need to keep track of how many times the app has been opened when all that is needed is a flag that indicates if this is the first launch or not?

Comment: We have to set one value in userDefaults. so whenever the app was opened we increment that number in **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions** function in the appDelegate.

Comment: Why? There is no requirement to keep a count.

Comment: @rmaddyYes, I call the **incrementNumberOfTimesLaunched** function from the **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions** function in the **appDelegate.**